# The SAP ERP organizational structure

Tags: data-structures, organization, sap-erp

SAP ERP software has quite a detailed organizational structure: what parts a client can have and how these parts can relate to each other.

E.g. a company code is an independent legal entity that belongs to a client and it has exactly one charts of accounts, i.e. rules that govern its accounting.

Company code, sales organization, plant, storage location and so on.

Is there an authorized full description of this hierarchy somewhere? There are various bits of it at:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_47x200/helpdata/EN/dd/563599aea111d199b60000e8a5bd28/frameset.htm

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/2082854

https://www.slideshare.net/DilipSadh1/sap-org-data-dilip-sadh

But I have found no full description of it.

Is there one on the Internet or in a book?

Answer (score 0):

SAP better calls this Enterprise Structure:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ERPLO/Enterprise+Structure

https://www.guru99.com/structures-in-sap.html

https://help.sap.com/doc/0d98cf535b804808e10000000a174cb4/3.6/en-US/699ecf535b804808e10000000a174cb4.html